# How to replace a pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have following dataframe:

```
                                         Scripts
1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677 || NA : 0 : 0 || NA : 0 : 0
```

The pattern I want replace is `'|| NA'` and whatever after that with whitespace. I am using following command in r to do it:

```
gsub("\\|| NA.*$","",df$Scripts)
```

But it replaces || in the middle between two scripts which I do not want. Desired output is:

```
1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by one or more `|` (as it is a metacharacter, we can either escape (`\\`) or place it in square brakcets  followed by one or more spaces, then NA and the rest of the characters, and replace it with `""`

```
sub("\\s*[|]+\\s+NA\\s+.*", "", df$Scripts)
#[1] "1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677"
```

NOTE: In the OP's code, it is just escaping the first `|`
 and not the second one.  Instead it should be

```
gsub("\\s*\\|+\\s*NA.*$", "", df$Scripts)
```

though `gsub` is not required

---

Or another option is `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace(df$Scripts, regex="\\s*\\|+\\s*NA.*$", "")
#[1] "1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Scripts = "1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677 || NA : 0 : 0 || NA : 0 : 0"), .Names = "Scripts", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex approach,

```
sapply(strsplit(df$Scripts, '||', fixed = TRUE), function(i) 
                     paste(i[!grepl('NA', i)], collapse = '||'))

#[1] "1:URT : 3456 || 2: ABC: 5677 "
```

You can wrap it in `trimws` to get rid of leading/following white spaces